# Retrieve emails associated with account

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, delete

I have some emails received from and sent to a specific email address that I deleted from my inbox.

I now need access to them (and their attachments) but am surprisingly not seeing them in my

1. Trash
2. Sent
3. All Mail

I've never really had this happen before. It's only been ~40 days since I deleted the emails.

I've recently sent a couple of emails to this same address and still see those in my 'sent'.

I'm guessing this specific email address has it set to permanently delete emails after 30 days or something? Never knew this was possible, just a guess.

Also, (if it comes to this) how can I put in a 'ticket' with Google to be able to retrieve these emails? It's only a couple and they're recent. I have to imagine they're still retrievable and not lost forever.

I did some reading and understand messages remain in trash' for 30 days before they're permanently deleted. That being said, I have 'sent' emails dating back to last year. How is it that sent emails to this specific address are gone?

I've also tried [Gmail Recovery tool](https://support.google.com/mail/workflow/9317561?visit_id=638139918970256906-3043780602&rd=1) to no avail

Comment: Please clarify how you are seeing "deleted emails from years ago".  Are you using the HTML Gmail or a different client or app?

Comment: HTML Gmail. Just the web app. But also seeing this on the iOS Mail App

Comment: So trash folder does seem to not retain anything after 30 (Except for one msg and idk why).

But..my sent still has messages from last year. 
So..I figured I could get attachment I need by looking at sent, but nothing to this address is there for some reason.

Do you want to send a masked screenshot of an old sent message? I can gladly do that

Comment: No need, do you use conversation View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conversation View

> How is it that sent emails to this specific address are gone?

It seems likely that you accidentally deleted email conversations from your Inbox thinking they were individual messages.

Each of these conversations may have looked like a single message but would have included multiple incoming and outgoing emails that would all have been moved to your Trash folder.

They would have been permanently deleted after 30 days.

> I'm guessing this specific email address has it set to permanently delete emails after 30 days or something?

No. That is not a possibility. The other user cannot control what happens to those messages in your account.

> how can I put in a 'ticket' with Google to be able to retrieve these emails?

I don't see that as an option.

Perhaps the other party to your email conversation can forward you the few messages in which you are interested.

### Avoiding this in the future

##### Option 1: Delete message not conversation

Steps: <sup>[[source]](https://support.google.com/answer/2451981)</sup>

1. Open the conversation
2. Find the specific message
3. Click the down arrow next to **Reply** at the top right of the message pane
4. Click **"Delete this message"**

##### Option 2: Turn off conversation view

Steps: <sup>[[source]](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900)</sup>

1. Open Gmail.
2. At the top right, click **Settings** and then **"See all settings"**
3. Scroll to **"Conversation view"**
4. Select **"Conversation View off"**

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense given what happened. There was back-and-forth and so it must've been conversation. Hm..SURELY Google recover lost emails for businesses and whatnot. Anything can be done at a price. I'd bet a million they have everything backed up on some form of glacial storage or tape drives. Just wondering where I can even reach them